# C# Regex in textbox just show "..."?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

```
        string input = "href http://www.url.com/news/world/391370/abc/abc/abc.htm"; // input
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"/([a-z0-9\-].+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // pattern
        if (match.Success)
        {
            string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(key);
        }
```

output

" http://www.url.com/news/world/391370/abc/abc/abc.htm "  it is work.!!

But in winForm textbox

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        string tb1 = Convert.ToString(textBox1);       // input
        string tb2 = Convert.ToString(textBox2);  // output
        Match match = Regex.Match(tb1, @"/([a-z0-9].+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
           textBox2.Text = key.ToString();
        }
```

Output

**"www.url.com/news/world/391370/abc..."**   <---  textbox cant show full result just display "..." instead , why ?  Please help.

Comment: Use .Text instead of Convert.ToString, that may fix it.

Comment: `key` is already a `string`, so why do you call `key.ToString()`? Makes absolutely no sense. About the `TextBox`: Maybe making it larger or using a `RichTextBox` instead will fix your problem?

Comment: This is nothing to do with RegEx

Answer (score 1):

Your textbox is physically not long enough to display all the data, the entire string.  you need to go to the form and make the textbox larger.  There are other properties of the textbox that you can use as well, which will prevent the ... from appearing, including an "auto-size" property.